# /libstdc++.so.6: version install not found

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, libstdc++, intel-edison

I am trying to use the praat tool on my Intel Edison, but the only library that is giving me is a problem is the libstdc++.so.6. The exact problem is that the tool requires a much older version of the library, specifically /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found. Is there any way that I can install this version specifically. When I do strings to check which versions are available, the only one that seems to be missing is 3.4.21. These are the versions that are available.

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
```

I need GLIBCXX_3.4.21. How can I install that version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and create soft link to library version, that is close to what you are missing, e.g. GLIBCXX_3.4.21 -> GLIBCXX_3.4.3/2. Perhaps that would work.

Comment: How do I do that especially in this case ? Because when I look for the library link itself and where it points to, this is the output :                                     root@edison:~# ls -l /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Jun 19  2015 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.20   (There is no sort of version that it is using, I believe it uses all of them as I posted above)

Comment: Able to install the newer version of gcc 5.3 and the newer version of that library comes with it. Just have to link it afterwards